# Resulting JSON has different structure

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I have a web application in which i use Spring MVC with Spring Hateoas with HypermediaType HAL. In my Controller i use the Resources Class to put in a list of Subjects.
The problem is, that if i put in a list of one element, the structure of the resulting json distinguishes from if i put in 2 elements.
If the list only contains one element it removes the list and returns it as a single object.
Below the two Controller methods i pasted the resulting Json.

I now want to know, why the behavior is like that and how can i force Hateoas to use a list in the resulting json?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/collections")
public class CollectionController {

    @RequestMapping
    public HttpEntity<Resources<Subject>> getOneSubject() {

        Subject subject = new Subject();
        Resources<Subject> subjects = new Resources<>(asList(subject));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(subjects, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
/*HTTP-Response Body:
{
    "_embedded": {
        "subject": {
            "name": null
        }
    }
}
*/


    @RequestMapping
    public HttpEntity<Resources<Subject>> getTwoSubjects() {

        Subject subject = new Subject();
        Resources<Subject> subjects = new Resources<>(asList(subject, subject));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(subjects, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
/*HTTP-Response Body:
{
    "_embedded": {
        "subjectList": [
            {
                "name": null
            },
            {
                "name": null
            }
        ]
    }
}*/

}
```

Hateoas configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class HateoasConfig {
}
```

Comment: Which library versions are you using? It feels like what you're complaining about was fixed in Spring HATEOAS 0.9…

Comment: I am using Spring HATEOAS 0.8. I can't test if 0.9 solves the problem, because when i update HATEOAS to 0.9 my Hateoas configuration to use HAL(i added the hateoas config to my first post) is ignored.

Comment: Now i updatet my Spring HATEOAS Version, to 0.10.0.TRAVERSON-SNAPSHOT, because with this, the problem with the ignored HAL config is fixed. Sadly the problem described in my first post still exists.

Comment: Simple 0.10.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT should do the trick as well. Any chance you provide a tiny test project that just serializes the two `Resources` instances via an `ObjectMapper` equipped with our `Jackson2HalModule`? The fix, I was thinking of actually made into 0.9: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/110

Comment: I added a test project to github: https://github.com/pongo710/HATEOAS-Tests. Little run information are in the README. The Project contains two tags 0.8 and 0.10. They stand for the HATEOAS versions. In 0.8 the problem described in my first post exists. In 0.10 the HAL config is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the example project you provided to run after the following steps:

1. Upgrade to a compatible Jackson version (2.3.0 or better). Use Spring HATEOAS 0.10.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
2. Run the app.
3. `curl -v -H "Accept: application/hal+json" http://localhost:8080/api/subjects`

Result:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc072803a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc072803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/subjects HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: application/hal+json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/hal+json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* Server Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/api/subjects"}},"_embedded":{"subjectList":[{"name":"foo"}]}}
```